# Get the scroll direction on swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm making a Snake Game. To move the snake, the player has to scroll on the screen. And I really need to know which was the direction of the scroll.
At first I tried this: I get where the player touches (pointOfTouch) and which was the previous point of touch (previousPointOfTouch).
Then, if the previousPointOfTouch.X minus the pointOfTouch.X is major than 0, the snake moves right.
The same thing goes for left, up and down (in up and down I get the Y coordinate)

It should work, and it does. But there's just one problem, it's too precise. If I scroll Up, like I do when I'm surfing the net, the App finds some little movements to left or right and moves the snake left and right.
How can I actually fix this ?

Here's the code I used

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch: AnyObject in touches{
            let pointOfTouch = touch.location(in: self)
            let previousPointOfTouch = touch.previousLocation(in: self)
            let amountDraggedX = pointOfTouch.x - previousPointOfTouch.x
            let amountDraggedY = pointOfTouch.y - previousPointOfTouch.y
            if amountDraggedY > 0 { //UP
                resetMoves() 
                moves[0] = true
            }
            else if amountDraggedY < 0 { //DOWN
                resetMoves()
                moves[1] = true
            }
            if amountDraggedX > 0 { //RIGHT
                resetMoves()
                moves[2] = true
            }
            else if amountDraggedX < 0 { //LEFT
                resetMoves()
                moves[3] = true
            }
        }
    }
```

- I declared a global array called  moves[] and it contains 4 element. It controls the Snake moves (if the first element is true, then the snake moves up)

```
var moves = [false, false, false, false]
```

- resetMoves() is a function I use to turn all the elements of the array  moves[]  to false. Then I change the item I need to true

Comment: Looks like you want to use UIPanGestureRecognizer. From velocity of the pan you will get direction of gesture

Comment: @Pikacz it would be great! But actually, I totally don't know how to use this... Do you have any link I can see to learn how to use this class?

Comment: Don't worry, find out this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zPF_kFn8mBA

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution to the problem.
Go on the file "GameViewController.swift". In the viewDidLoad() function

```
        let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipe(sender:)))

        let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipe(sender:)))
        leftSwipe.direction = .left

        let upSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipe(sender:)))
        upSwipe.direction = .up

        let downSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipe(sender:)))
        downSwipe.direction = .down

        view.addGestureRecognizer(upSwipe)
        view.addGestureRecognizer(downSwipe)
        view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)
        view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
```

now, out of this function write this:

```
@objc func handleSwipe(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
        if sender.state == .ended {
            switch sender.direction {
            case .up:
                //MOVES UP --> DO SOMETHING
            case .down:
                //MOVES DOWN --> DO SOMETHING
            case .right:
                //MOVES RIGHT --> DO SOMETHING
            case .left:
                //MOVES LEFT --> DO SOMETHING
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the code you should get on the "GameViewController.swift" file

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipe(sender:)))

        let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipe(sender:)))
        leftSwipe.direction = .left

        let upSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipe(sender:)))
        upSwipe.direction = .up

        let downSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSwipe(sender:)))
        downSwipe.direction = .down

        view.addGestureRecognizer(upSwipe)
        view.addGestureRecognizer(downSwipe)
        view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)
        view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)


        if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
            // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
            let scene = GameScene(size: CGSize(width:1536, height: 2048))
                // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
                scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

                // Present the scene
                view.presentScene(scene)

            view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            view.showsFPS = true
            view.showsNodeCount = true
        }
    }

    @objc func handleSwipe(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
        if sender.state == .ended {
            switch sender.direction {
            case .up:

            case .down:

            case .right:

            case .left:

            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }

    override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
            return .allButUpsideDown
        } else {
            return .all
        }
    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Now, if you want to communicate with the "GameScene.swift" file, you only have to declare a global variable.

To do this, you only have to declare it above the library importation. For example:

```
var movesController = [false, false, false, false]
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit
```

and then I can assign a function to each case:

```
           case .up:
                movesController[0]=true
            case .down:
                movesController[1]=true
            case .right:
                movesController[2]=true
            case .left:
                movesController[3]=true
            default:
                break
```

After doing this, you will be able to access to the array movesController even in the "GameScene.swift" file.

If movesController[0] == true ----> he's moving UP

If movesController[1] == true ----> he's moving DOWN

If movesController[2] == true ----> he's moving RIGHT

If movesController[3] == true ----> he's moving LEFT

To reset the array every time you can declare a reset function:

```
func resetMoves(){
        for i in 0...3 { //I can do 4 moves, so I have to overwrite 4 items (0,1,2,3)
            movesController[i] = false
        }
    }
```

and then call it in each case

```
            case .up:
                resetMoves()
                movesController[0]=true
            case .down:
                resetMoves()
                movesController[1]=true
            case .right:
                resetMoves()
                movesController[2]=true
            case .left:
                resetMoves()
                movesController[3]=true
            default:
                break
```